# How come `e.what()` prints "bad allocation"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception, object-slicing

The `new` expression in the `try` block throws a `bad_alloc`exception in my computer.

Note that the catch clause receives an exception object by value, not by reference. How come `e.what()` prints `"bad allocation"` ?  I thought it would be sliced.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int* p = new int[0x1F000000];
    }
    catch(std::exception e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just tried to allocate =~ 1.9375GB in your program. Are you compiling 32bit? Do you even have so much RAM in your machine?

Comment: @GMan  The compiler is MS VS 2008

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Visual Studio (Dinkumware?) uses an implementation of `std::exception` that contains internal storage† for the message. (Complete with a non-standard constructor that accepts a string.)

Because of this, no virtual dispatch is actually needed to get the error message, it survives any slicing.

A more orthodox implementation would indeed print a generic exception message, because the derived object was sliced off. (Effectively, MS has made `std::exception` and `std::runtime_error` equivalent. There's nothing wrong with this, since the return value of `std::exception::what` is implementation-defined, but it explains your results.)

---

†Internal storage here is used loosely. It doesn't have an internal *buffer*, but it has a `const char*` and a `bool`. The `const char*` points to the message (the return value of `what()`), and the `bool` is a flag determining if the buffer should be deleted.

It's like this:

```
class msvc_exception // for exposition
{
public:
    msvc_exception(const char* msg) :
    mMsg(msg),
    mDoDelete(false)
    {}

    msvc_exception(const std::string& msg) :
    mMsg(copy_string(msg)),
    mDoDelete(true)
    {}

    virtual ~msvc_exception()
    {
        if (mDoDelete)
            delete [] mMsg;
    }

    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return mMsg ? mMsg : "unknown";
    }

private:
    const char* copy_string(const std::string& str)
    {
        const char* result = new char[str.size() + 1];

        std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), result);
        result[str.size()] = 0; // null-terminate

        return result;
    }
};
```

You see now that `bad_alloc` works like this:

```
    class msvc_bad_alloc : // for exposition
        public msvc_exception
    {
    public:
        msvc_bad_alloc() :
        msvc_exception("bad_alloc") // note: a static string, no dynamic storage
        {}
    };
```

Slicing doesn't affect the message because the message "exists" in the base class.

Other compilers, like GCC and LLVM, implement it a bit more straight-forwardly:

```
class orthodox_exception
{
public:
    orthodox_exception(){}
    virtual ~orthodox_exception() {}

    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "orthodox_exception";
    }
};

class orthodox_bad_alloc :
    public orthodox_exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "orthodox_bad_alloc";
    }
};
```

Here, slicing would affect your outcome. (That said, after all this: always catch by reference.)

Comment: So you're saying that `exception` keeps a copy of the character string for all its derived classes ?

Comment: I would like to congratulate you for this excellent explanation. I'm a beginner. So it took me a while to understand it completely.